# Phonegap / Cordova Push Notification not waking up screen

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap, html-framework-7

I've been doing some research and `android` seems a bit stricter on waking up screen (light up device screen) when push notification is received.

What I would like to achieve is like a text message notification that it would turn on the screen, sound and vibrate. But my push notification only chime or vibrate. Is waking up the device from sleeping possible in cordova? I am using pubnub for the backend.

Here's my sample fcm payload:

        `var pushPayload = {
            "message": "Some message",
            "user_id": "1",
            "pn_gcm" : {
                "priority" : "high",
                "data" : {
                    "title":"Notification title",
                    "body":"You are a winner!",
                    "room" : "Room name",
                    //"count" : 5,
                    "content-available":"1",
                    "force-start": "1",
                    "priority":2
                }
            }

        };`

And here's my piece of AndroidManifest.xml

   `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="27" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />`

I am using `phonegap-plugin-push`.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I ended up creating my own cordova plugin just to handle on waking up screen. And here's the code that I used in my plugin:

```
    Context context = this.cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext();
    PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(context.POWER_SERVICE);

    boolean result= Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH&&powerManager.isInteractive()|| Build.VERSION.SDK_INT< Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH&&powerManager.isScreenOn();

    if (!result){
        PowerManager.WakeLock wl = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK |PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP |PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE,"MH24_SCREENLOCK");
        wl.acquire(10000);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wl_cpu = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,"MH24_SCREENLOCK");
        wl_cpu.acquire(10000);
    }`
```

So, in the `notification` event, I called my plugin like this:

` 
push.on('notification', function(data) {

```
    //call wakeup screen
    window.plugins.wakeUpScreen.wakeup(function() {
      console.log('Wake up!');
    }, function(err) {
      console.log('Wake up error: ' + err);
    });          

}); `
```

Answer (score 0):

Android devices have their own notification preferences and some cannot be overridden by your app. The "Ambient Display" setting will have the screen wake upon notification, but this is a feature that must be turned on in the phone settings.